# Multiplying Argument

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I'm solving the following problem: Sketch the image of the set $$\{ Arg(z) \geq \frac{\pi}{2} \text{ and } 1 \leq |z| \leq 2\}$$ by the function $f(z) = z^3$.

What I tried so far: $z^3 =  r^3e^{3\theta i}$. Then,

\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
        1 &\leq r^3 \leq 8 \\
        3\pi/2 &\leq 3Arg(\theta) 
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

This is where I am stuck. How do you know where to stop starting from $3\pi/2$? 3rd quadrant can be  $\geq 3/2\pi$.

I know the correct solution is the image above by plugging in three random but easy points from the domain. Is there any way to know where the graph should stop (radian-wise) without having to plug in values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first condition can be written as: $$\{\pi/2\le \arg(z)\le \pi/2 \text{ and }1\le|z|\le2\}.$$ Hence, the image of the domain would be $$\{3\pi/2\le \arg(z)\le 3\pi/2 \text{ and }1\le|z|\le8\} .$$